# You throw no low blows and rise above the rest

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, phrase-meaning

> You throw no low blows and rise above the rest.

What does it mean?

Comment: Pam, when you are quoting something, please make that obvious. The right way is to put > first, followed by the text. `> You throw no low blows...`

Comment: Okay, I will..I know It's a little vague. anyway Thank you!

Comment: @Pam edit your question and see what Andrew meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary helps:

> [**low blow**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/low-blow) *noun*
>   *Boxing*
>   an unlawful blow that lands below an opponent’s waist:
>   *the referee hadn’t seen the low blow and declined to call a timeout*
>   a comment or tactic regarded as unfair or unkind:
>   *his mockery of Elizabeth’s work seemed like a low blow*
>
> [**rise above**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rise#rise__13) *verb*
>   succeed in not being limited or constrained by (a restrictive environment or situation):
>   *he struggled to rise above his humble background*
>   be superior to:
>   *I try to rise above prejudice*
>
> [ODO]

*Low blow* comes straight from boxing but has been applied metaphorically to any unfair or underhand act.

“You do not act unfairly and are better than everyone else, who does act like that.”

Comment: @Pam I reckon this question is **just about** on-topic here because it deals with metaphors. **But** it can be answered by reference to a dictionary, which means it may still be closed (and then possibly deleted). Do break down your sentences into small parts and look those up. Online dictionaries such as ODO do list phrases.